# How to remove kernel from the yocto rootfs

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

It was possible to not deliver Kernel image together with rootfs image. From yocto Dunfell documentation:

```
To specify whether or not the kernel image is installed in the generated root filesystem, 
override RDEPENDS_${KERNEL_PACKAGE_NAME}-base to include or not include “kernel-image”.
```

Starting from yocto version honister variable name was changed to `RDEPENDS:${KERNEL_PACKAGE_NAME}-base`.
I am using yocto kirkstone version 4.0 and this variable does not make any effect.
Does somebody know if it is a bug o feature in the new version?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with kirkstone and found out that new line is:

RRECOMMENDS:${KERNEL_PACKAGE_NAME}-base = ""